# Android rounding corners in layout with different radius values

Tags: android

I'm trying to make an intention which has a transparent background, and a solid foreground with some basic info and rounded corners.
Currently I can use a shape with a rounded corners if all the corners are the same radius using

```
<corners android:radius="20dp" />
```

But if I try to have, say, just the bottom rounded like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<solid
android:color="#cccccc" />
<corners android:radius="20dp" android:topLeftRadius="0dp"
    android:topRightRadius="0dp" 
    android:bottomLeftRadius="20dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="20dp" />
</shape>
```

or anything similar, then I get an error in my layout which says

> layout.xml: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try dropping the `android:radius=20dp` and just have the individual radii.  Also, you should probably switch to `dip` instead of `dp`.

Comment: Tried it without the radius=20dp part at first, but according to the google docs it's best to keep that in to initialize if you are going to make any other corners a radius of zero.

Comment: Here is a copy of my shape that works.  I'm pretty hard pressed to find a difference.  `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
     android:shape="rectangle"> 
     <gradient android:startColor="#FAEBD7" 
       android:endColor="#FFFFF0" 
            android:angle="270"/> 

    <corners android:bottomRightRadius="0dip" android:bottomLeftRadius="0dip" 
     android:topLeftRadius="7dip" android:topRightRadius="7dip"/> 
</shape>`

Comment: just copy and pasted that one to see if it would work on mine, and it returned the same error. I have no idea why having just android:radius will work, but not this...